# Fixed background images causing scroll lags

Tags: html, css, lag

Long time reader, new poster here...
I've found similar questions, but none of the solutions worked for me.
I'm working on a single page website (html css only) where some DIVs have images as background (`background-attachment: fixed` and `background-size: cover;`).
That makes the scrolling very laggy in several browsers, especially in Chrome.
(interestingly, the scrolling is smooth in Firefox).

Some people suggested using `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`, others suggested using webkit resources, and at some point I've even found something about `will-change: transform;` - which, to be honest, I didn't completely understand. 
anyway, I've tried to use all that, but failed.

How can I prevent lagging? I prefer pure CSS solutions, but I'm open to other stuff.
(and sorry if I'm not clear, or did repeated a question)

Comment: Post the code here.

Comment: I can't post full code here, because it's work related, maybe if I write some generic one?

Comment: Generic one will work.

Comment: A sample in jsfiddle would be useful.

Comment: try https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property/